# pdnsd in 12.04LTS precise pangolin

Tags: 12.04, resolv.conf

how to install and configure pdnsd to make it work

I tried configuring my self but couldn't make that work now I've removed that and asked here for help

I also messed up the /etc/pdnsd.conf and usr/share/default/pdnsd files please help needed as soon as possible step by step

this error i get when ever i try restart pdnsd

`root@Citilink:/home/citilink# service pdnsd restart                              * Stopping pdnsd                                                                  ...done.                                                                      * Starting pdnsd                                                               Error: unknown option: no`

This is my /etc/pdnsd.conf

`// Read the pdnsd.conf(5) manpage for an explanation of the options.                                                                                            /* Note: this file is overriden by automatic config files when                     /etc/default/pdnsd AUTO_MODE is set and that                                    /usr/share/pdnsd/pdnsd-$AUTO_MODE.conf exists                                                                                                                                                                                                global {                                                                                perm_cache=;1024000                                                             server_ip = 127.0.0.1;  // Use eth1 here if you want to allow other                                     // machines on your network to query pdnsd.             status_ctl = on;                                                                paranoid=on;                                                                    query_method=tcp_udp;   // pdnsd must be compiled with tcp                                              // query support for this to work.                      min_ttl=15m;       // Retain cached entries at least 15 minutes.                max_ttl=1w;        // One week.                                                 timeout=10;        // Global timeout option (10 seconds).                                                                                                       // Don't enable if you don't recurse yourself, can lead to problems             // delegation_only="com","net";                                         }                                                                               server {                                                                                              label= "citilink";                                                              ip=8.8.8.8,4.2.2.2;10.0.0.1                                                     proxy_only=on;                                                                  timeout=10;                                                             }                                                                                                                                                 server {                                                                                 ip = 10.0.0.1;  Put your ISP's DNS-server address here.                         interface=eth1;     The interface connected to the network.            }                                                                                with status_ctl=on and resolvconf installed, this will work out from the box      this is the recommended setup for mobile machines */                         server {                                                                            label="resolvconf";                                                         }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                This section is meant for resolving from root servers.                         server {                                                                                label = "root-servers";                                                         root_server=on;                                                                 ip =    198.41.0.4                                                              ,       192.228.79.201                                                          ,       192.33.4.12                                                             ,       128.8.10.90                                                             ,       192.203.230.10                                                          ,       192.5.5.241                                                             ,       192.112.36.4                                                            ,       128.63.2.53                                                             ,       192.36.148.17                                                           ,       192.58.128.30                                                           ,       193.0.14.129                                                            ,       198.32.64.12                                                            ,       202.12.27.33                                                            ;                                                                               timeout = 5;                                                                    uptest = query;                                                                 interval = 30m;      // Test every half hour.                                   ping_timeout = 300;  // 30 seconds.                                             purge_cache = off;                                                              exclude = .localdomain;                                                         policy = included;                                                              preset = off;                                                           }                                                                                                                                                                       owner=localhost;                                                        //      serve_aliases=on;                                                               file="/etc/hosts";                                                      }                                                                                                                                                               rr {                                                                                    name=localhost;                                                                 reverse=on;                                                                     a=127.0.0.1;                                                                    owner=localhost;                                                                soa=localhost,root.localhost,42,86400,900,86400,86400;                  }                                                                                                                                                               /*                                                                              neg {                                                                                   name=doubleclick.net;                                                           types=domain;   // This will also block xxx.doubleclick.net, etc.       }                                                                               */                                                                                                                                                              /*                                                                              neg {                                                                                   name=bad.server.com;   // Badly behaved server you don't want to connect to.                                                                                    types=A,AAAA;                                                           }                                                                               */                                                                                                                                                              /* vim:set ft=c: */                                                                                                                                                                                                           102,0-1       Bot`

Answer (score 0):

To correct your errors execute the following command in a Terminal window.

`sudo apt-get purge pdnsd`

Simply installing the pdnsd package suffices to make pdnsd work as a caching forwarding nameserver.

`sudo apt-get install pdnsd`

If you have a more specific need then please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Dear @jdthood please let me know if my pdnsd.conf is not configured wrongly i did the exact step after getting the unknown error as mentioned above and according your suggestion

Comment: Dear @jdthood i used this link to manage my pdnsd please tell what more need to me done in config like i think i missed setting my own ttl and ping reply time in it http://www.howtoforge.com/pdnsd-howto-a-dns-caching-personal-server-fedora-16

Comment: Seems you used instructions intended for Fedora. This is Ubuntu. Ubuntu is different from Fedora in many ways including the way that services are configured by default and the way that resolv.conf is managed. Ubuntu uses resolvconf to manage resolv.conf. You have not told us what your goal is, so for now I will just advise you to read the relevant documentation *in Ubuntu* or to read online howtos *for Ubuntu*.

Comment: Dear @jdthood im so glad your answer work for me i was confused about server any how my Pdnsd running and working fine well now i got another issue i'll reveal it in other question